# Magento 2 how to remove/disable title/word below every single image in product page

Tags: product, magento-2.2.5

[image: remove image]

I need to remove the image title/name below from product view pages. Magento version 2.2.5. Anyone know how do this?

The expectation is without title/name :)

Comment: Are you using any theme?

Comment: please try to remove label name of image

Comment: i am using porto theme. @SukumarGorai

Comment: @pramod24 do you where to remove label name of image? default didn't give name for image upload on backend.

Comment: @pramod24 It will not work.

Comment: @SukumarGorai do you have any solutions?

Comment: Can you share the url? You can manage it through css which is the last solution.

Comment: Check the my answer?

Comment: @SukumarGorai cannot fixed it. can check this link. https://www.designerpurses.ru/louis-vuitton-lv-backpack-pm-monogram-titanium-m43882.html

Comment: Where did you change the mentioned lines? Delete the 2 files under pub/static/frontend/Dapl/demo/en_US/fotorama/ then flush the cache and run static content deploy and check.

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the **fotoroma.js** from location to your module:

> lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.js

Then find **showcaption** and **captions**, then set those to **false**.

Now need to run static content deploy.

I have edited the

> lib/web/fotoroma/fotoroma.js

directly
This solved my problem.

Comment: ,can you tell please how to remove product image scroll in details page in fotorama.js

Comment: Post a question with screenshot, definitely members will answer.

Comment: it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a custom module with below code.

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml
```

With below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery">
        <plugin name="get_gallery_images_json_captions" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Gallery"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Now plugin file

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Gallery.php
```

With below code.

```
<?php

namespace Kunj\Gallery\Plugin;
class Gallery
{
    public function afterGetGalleryImagesJson(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $galleryOptions = json_decode($result,1);
        foreach ($galleryOptions as $k => $options)
        {
            if(isset($galleryOptions[$k]) && isset($galleryOptions[$k]['caption']))
            {
                $galleryOptions[$k]['caption'] = "";

            }
        }
        return json_encode($galleryOptions);
    }
}
```

Now flush the cache and deploy static content.

Comment: just try it, it doesn't work, i guess somethings about fotorama.

Comment: Actually, magento display that data from $data varibale wich is in gallery.phtml file and there's bug in magento 2 as if we set caption false in current theme etc/view.xml file under var section. Did you create custom module?

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your custom css.

```
.fotorama__caption{
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also using magento 2 and Porto theme, for people who needs to do it via CSS can follow the following steps:

- Goto Store > Configurations > Porto theme Settings Panel > Custom CSS

Add following css.

```
.fotorama__caption__wrap{
display:none !important;
```

}

After that clear the cache of magento and browser. The caption/label now must be hidden.